# Show or hide DataTables column according to the screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, datatable

I am using the datatable to display information

https://datatables.net/

And my code to create datatable is like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="datatable_<?= $key; ?>" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Thumbnail</th>
         <th>Teacher</th>
         <th>Pose</th>
         <th>Style</th>
         <th>Level</th>
         <th>Create Date</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php
         foreach ($playlist as $item) {
             if ($item['type'] == $key) {
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td><a href='" . site_url("video/view/" . $item['id']) . "' target='_blank'>" . $item[set_lang('title')] . "</a></td>";
                 echo "<td><img src='" . (isset($item['image_url']) ? site_url("thumbnail/" . $item['image_url']) : $item['thumbnail']) . "' height='60'></td>";
                 echo "<td>" . set_lang($item ['name']) . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . print_array($item['pose']) . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . print_array($item ['style']) . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . $this->level_list[$item ['level']] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item['create_date'])) . "</td>";
                 echo "<td><label class='block option option-primary'><input type='checkbox' name='videos[]' value='" . $item['id'] . "'><span class='checkbox'></span></label></td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
             }
         }
         ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
    var myTable = $('#datatable_0, #datatable_1').dataTable({
        order: [[5, "desc"]],
        iDisplayLength: 5,
        aLengthMenu: [
            [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
            [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
        ],
        sDom: '<"dt-panelmenu clearfix"lfr>t<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
        oTableTools: {
            sSwfPath: "<?= site_url("vendor/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"); ?>"
        }
    });
```

There are 8 column in total .

I would like to achieve: if screen width < 700px , then only show the 1st and last column.

Notices that the order column should be change to last column as well.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then add the classes to the required row which you want to hide when <700px 
 Add class to `th`

```
<th class="hideClass">Level</th>
```

Add class to `td`

```
echo "<td class="hideClass">" . $this->level_list[$item ['level']] . "</td>";
```

Add this in your css file

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {.hideClass{display:none;}}
```

this will work

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this ?

> via CSS only with media query :

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    table th, table td{
       display:none;
    }
    table th:first-child, table th:last-child, 
    table td:first-child, table td:last-child{
        display:table-cell;
    }
}
```

> via jQuery

```
function fittabletoscreen(){
    if(jQuery(window).width()<700){
      //hide all th,td and show only first and last
      jQuery('table th, table td').hide();
      jQuery('table th:first-child, table th:last-child, table td:first-child, table td:last-child').show();

      //Optional to hide and show
      //jQuery('table th, table td').css('display','none');
      //jQuery('table th:first-child, table th:last-child, table td:first-child, table td:last-child').css('display','table-cell');
   }
}
```

And call this function on resizing window too;

```
fittabletoscreen();  //initial call
jQuery(window).resize(function(){  //change in landscape and portrait view
   fittabletoscreen(); 
}
```